# Apple Photos on Mac does not analyse a very specific set of pics

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I have imported some pics recently, and although they have been "analysed" in the main tab (Library), they remain as "427 Photos remaining" in the People's tab.
In the meantime, I imported yet another set of pics, and these new imports have been successfully analysed in both tabs, leaving me again with the remaining 427 pics.

I have looked in the SQLite database, and there seems to be a correlation in number between these pics and the pics tagged with a **ZANALYSISSTATE=-30** in the ZASSETANALYSISSTATE table.

Performing the following query highlighted the fact that the directories matches the dates at which the problem started to occur:

```
select zdirectory from zasset zad
inner join ZASSETANALYSISSTATE ZAS
    on zad.zuuid=zas.ZASSETUUID
where zas.ZANALYSISSTATE = -30
group by zdirectory
```

What does -30 mean ?

How to fix this?